# Unexpected strings in tags after v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm now writing a web page with Vue on Nuxt to replace the old one.(VScode)
And I faced the problem that when I used v-for to create lists,
inside the tag there's a unknown string(attribute).
And this unknown string seemed to effect my CSS, so it really bothers me.

p.s.
I'm rookie on web design. 
I guess is the v-bind key, which I haven't fully understood effects the result
Thanks for your answering!

The unknown string(attribute): data-v-768556b7=""

```
<a data-v-768556b7="" href="#">Notebook</a>
```

And here's part of my code:

```
<div class="prod-sub-menu products-menu sub-menu">
              <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li
                  v-for="(pName, index) in productMenuList"
                  :id="pName.idName"
                  :key="index"
                  class="prod-sub-item sub-item current"
                >
                  <a :href="pName.url">{{pName.menuName}}</a>
                  <ul v-for="(subName,index2) in pName['subMenu']" :key="index2">
                    <li>
                      <a :href="subName.url">{{subName.subMenuName}}</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              ...

             ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know the data-v string appears when you're using scoped css.

Here is the documentation for it: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html

Are you by any chance using

```
<style scoped>
/* Your css here */
</style>
```

If you are, that might be the problem. Try just removing the scoped word.

Comment: Yes! It's gone. But still can't get my css. And there's still a weird thing I forgot to mention that the class I set is different to the class it shows in tag. Anyway thx so much for ur help!!!

Comment: Are you getting no css or a wrong style? If you're getting no, it's probably because this weird bug with the class name (maybe a typo?). If you are getting the wrong style is probably because you have another css file that is interfering in this sub-menu code... Well, that is all I can think off without seeing the rest of the code. Hope it is of some help